# Sentry events are not connected with sourcemaps

Tags: react-native, source-maps, sentry

[image]

New Events are uploaded and soucemap is connected. but still i see this issue.

[image]

All this events are displayed at release 1.0 . But still i see source maps are not connected .
[image]

Comment: did you find a solution i am having the same problem ?

Comment: Not yet still !!!

Comment: I'm having the same issue. Did you ever figure this out?

Answer (score 0):

Try renaming `index.ios.bundle` to `~/index.ios.bundle`.

Comment: Did you try renaming to exactly `app:///index.ios.bundle`. What version of Sentry are you running?